# Set different PDF page box on odd and even pages

Tags: pdf, everypage

How can I globally set different PDF page boxes on odd and even pages?

I tried using the `everypage` package but it does not seem to actually insert the PDF page box into the current page object.

I can use `\pdfpageattr` on a page directly and the page box is set properly.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]}
  \else
    \pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [216 216 360 360]}
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\null
%\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]}% directly inserting on each page works
\clearpage
\null
%\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [216 216 360 360]}% directly inserting on each page works
\end{document}
```

The above file gives a PDF containing (no ArtBox):

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.276 841.89]
/Parent 4 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [ /PDF ]
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Length 0         
>>
stream

endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Contents 7 0 R
/Resources 5 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.276 841.89]
/Parent 4 0 R
>>
endobj
```

If I uncomment the `\pdfpageattr` lines in the body of the document I get what I want:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.276 841.89]
/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]
/Parent 4 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [ /PDF ]
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Length 0         
>>
stream

endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Contents 7 0 R
/Resources 5 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.276 841.89]
/ArtBox [216 216 360 360]
/Parent 4 0 R
>>
endobj
```

Comment: `\AtBeginShipout{\ifodd\c@page ... ` (with atbegshi) will work. But be aware that you are overwriting other uses of \pdfpageattr here, e.g. from hyperref, tagpdf, fancytoolstips, pdflscape, pdfx.

Comment: I'd recommend to add those boxes to your page styles, that is, include them into your `\@oddfoot` and `\@evenfoot`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks. That works. Feel free to add a quick answer if you like.

Comment: @Lupino, I had tried using `fancyhdr` but that didn't work either. But feel free to add answer if you can make it work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, BTW, why doesn't it work with `everypage`?

Comment: everypage places its hook around \@outputpage, and this is in a group, so you need `\global\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that you are overwriting other uses of \pdfpageattr here, e.g. from hyperref, tagpdf, fancytoolstips, pdflscape, pdfx.

everypage places its hook in a group, so you need to make the setting global. There is imho no need to use ifoddpage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfcompresslevel0
\pdfobjcompresslevel0
\usepackage{everypage}
\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{
  \ifodd\c@page
    \global\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]}
  \else
    \global\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [216 216 360 360]}
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\null
%\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]}% directly inserting on each page works
\clearpage
\null
%\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [216 216 360 360]}% directly inserting on each page works
\end{document}
```

The alternative is atbegshi:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfcompresslevel0
\pdfobjcompresslevel0
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginShipout{
  \ifodd\c@page
    \global\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]}
  \else
    \global\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [216 216 360 360]}
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\null
%\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [72 72 216 216]}% directly inserting on each page works
\clearpage
\null
%\pdfpageattr{/ArtBox [216 216 360 360]}% directly inserting on each page works
\end{document}
```